# .htaccess Redirect Google Bot to prerender service passing full URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using Wordpress Multisite, and some of my pages I have built using javascript. So naturally, my SEO sucks. So I have created a phantom.js prerender.io service hosted on myurl.com:3000

I am trying to redirect google bots to use the prerender service. I need to pass the full url to the prerender service like this: http://myurl.com:3000/http://sub.myurl.com/cats/are/cool

As you can see, I am using subdirectory wordpress multisite, so the subdomain and domain need to be passed.

## First Problem

This is the original wordpress .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I have tried to use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://example.com [P,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
...
```

Just for testing, I run http://myurl.com?_escaped_fragment_= in my browser and I get a page like this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

It doesn't even seem to redirect to http://service.prerender.io. I'm guessing there is some kind of conflict with the wordpress rules.

**Update: This issue was fixed by turning on mod_proxy, thanks to @Jon Lin**

## Second Problem

Once I pop in the right url (http://myurl.com:3000), I have no idea how to grab the entire URL to give to the service! I have googled and google, and I can only find information about how to get url parameters after the domain.

First problem first though, second is only bonus. I can discuss that in another question when I am able to tested it better because the first problem is fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_proxy loaded? The `P` flag won't do anything unless you have mod_proxy loaded in your server config.

Comment: That did it! Sorry I didn't know what the P flag stood for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jon Lin for the mod_proxy answer.

For the second answer, check the following gist for the rewrite rule for grabbing the entire URL to give to the service. It does a quick check to make sure you are most likely trying to view an html file, then adds the entire URL on the end of the request.

https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354

Basically:

> RewriteRule
>   ^(?!.*?(.js|.css|.xml|.less|.png|.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.pdf|.doc|.txt|.ico|.rss|.zip|.mp3|.rar|.exe|.wmv|.doc|.avi|.ppt|.mpg|.mpeg|.tif|.wav|.mov|.psd|.ai|.xls|.mp4|.m4a|.swf|.dat|.dmg|.iso|.flv|.m4v|.torrent))(.*)
>   http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]

Comment: You see how it has "http://example.com", I can't have that because I will have subdomains sometimes. So it needs to send the full url from the browser.

Comment: Updated the answer to include %{HTTP_HOST}. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok this worked best for me: "http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]". So I have sent my prerender service to an heroku app. But the service takes so long to respond that google is unable to grab anything. See here: http://damp-dusk-7268.herokuapp.com/http://admissions.wnmu.edu/undergrad/ It looks like its trying to find all the css files on the heroku server rather than wnmu.edu. So it waits for request timeout.. can i make it ignore missing requests faster?Or make it look for the files on wnmu.edu? Thats what I thought [p] should do. thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah i did some more testing. Very strange, it takes forever for my website to load through prerender, I have tried just running the default on the heroku instance, and it still took forever. It seems to load ok on service.prerender.io though. Any idea what might be different?

Comment: Ok. I'll update my answer with your comment. Are you proxying the request through your server instead going to that URL in your browser?  When proxied through your server (and using the regex from above), it should only send the request for the page, not the css.

Comment: Nope i was requesting through the server. It takes like 40 secs to load... in the network tab of chrome inspector i see its stuff for 10 seconds on css files that heroku returns as 502.

Comment: Hmm, send me an email at todd@prerender.io and I can look into it locally. css files shouldn't be proxied.